# Documentation style spec running for jasmine(-headless-webkit)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, jasmine

I am using jasmine for javascript testing. How can I set the get the full specification like listing of the tests instead of the '.......' format?

As I test using guard, the set of actually executed tests is rather small, I find listing the full specification lines more useful. Thanks for helping out with a tip for configuring jasmine.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a Verbose reporter to `jasmine-headless-webkit`. Try it out with:

`jasmine-headless-webkit -f Verbose`

If you've got any comments on it, leave a note in the GH issues and I'll take a look.

Comment: great, thanks, I've seen it on github as well, will try it out for sure.